# Python Selenium: How to go to a google search URL without the page showing up as "not found", "access forbidden", or "permission denied"

Tags: python, regex, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just began working with Selenium to learn about webscraping and I am trying to now run a google search, then iterate my code over each of the top 5 URLs that my search returned.

My google search would load properly, but when I go to any of the search result URLs the page would show a "not found", "access forbidden", or "permission denied" page. This happens as well if I manually paste the URL in. How can I bypass this?

Or am I going to the next URL improperly? I am currently resetting the driver.get URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import re

search = '5 most popular dog breeds'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/#q=' + search)
b = driver.current_url
page = requests.get(b)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
links = soup.findAll("a")
urlList = []

# Put first 5 URLs of search into array x.
for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    urlList.append(re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))
    if len(urlList) == 5:
        break

driver.get(urlList[0][0])
url = driver.current_url
page = requests.get(url)
pgsource = driver.page_source
```

Comment: What are the actual urls that you're trying to get?

Comment: Also, since that search phrase contains spaces and you're trying to use it directly in a url, you should probably `urlescape` it first.

Comment: I already grabbed the 5 URLs I needed, now I just want to go to each of them, but after my google search page, when it tries to jump to the URLs, they lead to a permission denied page most of the time.

Comment: Do the URLs work if you manually copy/paste in the address bar?

Comment: @0buz No, they are still access denied

Comment: Can you share some of the URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening pages correctly. It looks like you are pulling extra query parameters when getting `href` for the `a` elements.

I modified your code to only get links that match this regex pattern for links `'https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/]+'` and to only take 1 link per web element (in your case it sometimes was 2).

```
# Put first 5 URLs of search into array x.
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    r = re.findall(pattern=re.compile('https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/]+'), string=link['href'])[0]
    urlList.append(r)

    if len(urlList) == 5:
        break

print(urlList[0])
driver.get(urlList[0])
pgsource = driver.page_source
print(pgsource)
```

You can also just use Selenium for the same purpose, without Beautiful Soup, it'll look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

search = '5 most popular dog breeds'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/#q=' + search)
# Using XPath to filter desired elements instead of regex:
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href!='' and contains(@ping,'/url?sa')]")

urls = []
for link in links[1:6]:
    urls += [link.get_attribute('href')]

print(urls[0])
driver.get(urls[0])
pgsource = driver.page_source
print(pgsource)
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps, good luck.